# Moving label of empty arrow in xypic

Tags: math-mode, diagrams, xy-pic

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/pushouts-and-pullbacks) about typesetting pullback square has almost everything I want, except the placement of the 'corner' symbols to be in the corner of the diagram, and not in the center.

My problem a conflict between placing the label in the middle of the empty arrow, i.e using `\ar@{}[dr]|{\ulcorner}`, and moving the label to the very end of the arrow as on the bottom right corner of page 4 [of the `xypic` manual](http://www.math.wichita.edu/~pparker/personal/latex/xyguide), achieved by `\ar[r]^>{\ulcorner}`.

Writing out `\ar{}[dr]^>|{\ulcorner}` does not give the desired result. How can I move a label along the an empty arrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, sorry, `\ar{}[dr]|>{\ulcorner}` works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/96058)

Comment: @StefanPinnow I think this does answer the question, presuming that it gives the OP the output they are looking for