# correct placement of pullback corner for non-square rectangular diagrams in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

The recommended way (see Section 4.2 [here](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf)) to place pullback corners in `tikz-cd` diagrams is using diagonal phantom arrows, as in

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    A   \arrow[r] 
        \arrow[d] 
        \arrow[dr, phantom, "\lrcorner", very near start] 
&   B   \arrow[d] 
\\  C   \arrow[r] 
&   D  
\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

However, this isn't great when the diagram deviates too far from the square shape, eg because of long labels:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    A   \arrow[r] 
        \arrow[d] 
        \arrow[dr, phantom, "\lrcorner", very near start] 
&   B   \arrow[d] 
\\  CCCC\arrow[r] 
&   DDDD  
\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is that the `\lrcorner` is further from the left arrow than from the upper arrow.

I can adjust that manually with `shift right`, but I wonder if there's a method that doesn't place the corner on an invisible diagonal of the rectangle, but rather at a fixed distance at a 45 degree angle from the center of the upper left corner?

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503556/193342) seems to do something like this, but with `tikzpicture` instead of `tikzcd`, and I don't know how to adapt it to `tikzcd`.

Comment: If it denotes something about the *A* use labels, i.e. `|[label=south east:$\lrcorner$]| A`. Or pics placed like labels: [See 2. and 3.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688989). We could also draw a segment of the node's border if that's better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place the `\lrcorner` symbol as a `label` for the node. You can set the angle and distance.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    |[label={[label distance=-2mm]-45:\lrcorner}]|A   \arrow[r] 
        \arrow[d]  
&   B   \arrow[d] 
\\  CCCC\arrow[r] 
&   DDDD
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add whatever `tikz` code you like with the `execute at end picture` hook.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={\path (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1) node[below right]{$\lrcorner$};}]
    A   \arrow[r] 
        \arrow[d] 
&   B   \arrow[d] 
\\  CCCC\arrow[r] 
&   DDDD  
\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also use the `pic` from the [linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503556/).