# how to avoid this change of size in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I was happy to learn [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/690106/193342) how to place "pullback-corner" decorations in tikz-cd squares using labels instead of phantom diagonals, but now I noticed that the label technique seems to affect the dimensions of the diagram. The code

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
U\cap V \ar[r] \ar[d] & V \ar[d] \\
U \ar[r] & |[label={[label distance=-3mm]135:\ulcorner}]| P
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
\begin{tikzcd}
U\cap V \ar[r] \ar[d] & V \ar[d] \\
U \ar[r] & P 
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
\begin{tikzcd}
U\cap V \ar[r] \ar[d] & V \ar[d] \\
U \ar[r] & P \ar[ul, phantom,"\ulcorner",pos=0]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

produces the following diagram:

[image: three squares]

The left square, using label, is larger than the middle square without decoration, and the right square with the decoration placed on a phantom diagonal.

Is there a way to avoid this resizing?

Comment: You can use `overlay` with the label (`label={[overlay]…}`) so that it does not affect the bounding box of the cell. You can also use a “late label” as I call it, i.e. a label that is placed after the matrix has been constructed, basically `\arrow[to path={node also[label=…]](\tikztostart)}]` (but we can make a nice style out of it), see [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688989) for a wider discussion about this. You can also use `between origins` with the column and row separation which will ignore everything in each cell.

Comment: great, thanks! overlay works. if you want to add an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the TO mentions in his comment, that the proposal made solved his/her problem.

Comment: Why has this been marked as off topic